# I want to get min value of the column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column with the min value of compare_at_price. If data contains value we can easily get the min value by 
`sumList1 = udf(lambda c: min(c), IntegerType())`. But I am having comma alone in some rows in the dataframe.

```
+--------------------+

|    compare_at_price|

+--------------------+

|               [,,,]|

|                  []|

|               [,,,]|

|[89.95, 89.95, 89.95|

|                  []|

|                  []|
```

Can you please help me to solve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the minimum of the ArrayType columns in teh following way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,array_min

resultDF = df.select(array_min(col("compare_at_price")).alias('min_price'))

resultDF.show(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly import**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{min, max}
```

**And then,**

```
df.agg(min("compare_at_price")).show()
```